# Numpy error when creating ragged nested sequences

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following Numpy array with will have a shape of (3, N):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[4, 4, 4, 7], [6, 6, 8, 9], [2, 4, 10, 29]])
```

I have a function named `get_wheel_status`:

```
def get_wheel_status(arr, Dr, Dl, Db):
    
    delta_right = arr[0,:]
    delta_left  = arr[1,:]
    delta_back = arr[2,:]
    
    delta_theta = (delta_left - delta_right) / (Dr + Dl)
    delta_theta_cumul = np.cumsum(delta_theta, axis=0)
    
    delta_x = 2*np.sin(delta_theta/2) * np.array([(delta_back / delta_theta) + Db])
    delta_y = 2*np.sin(delta_theta/2) * np.array([(delta_right / delta_theta) + Dr])

    delta_x_cumul = np.cumsum(delta_x, axis=0)
    delta_y_cumul = np.cumsum(delta_y, axis=0)
  
    return np.array([[delta_theta_cumul], [delta_x_cumul], [delta_y_cumul]])
```

I want to return a (3, N) matrix.  But, when I pass the following:

```
get_wheel_status(arr, 1, 1, 1)
```

I get this error:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return np.array([[delta_theta_cumul], [delta_x_cumul], [delta_y_cumul]])
```

Can someone please help me understand why my return statement is causing this 'ragged nested sequence'?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the dimensions of the three arrays in that return the same?

Comment: This is just warning not error. As it is  said in the warning massage, if the shapes are the same, so it is related to use of list of arrays in the return. If getting the warning matter, do as [*proper solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72906933/13394817) or inactive such warnings in the code with numpy (which is not recommended)

Comment: @hpaulj -- The dimensions are the same, yes.

Comment: No they aren't.  `delta_theta` is (n,), `delta_x` is (1,n).  The answer remove unnecessary [] in several places, each of which adds a dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Quick Fix**

A quick fix would be to add `dtype=object` to the `np.array` that is being returned by the function. In particular,

```
np.array([[delta_theta_cumul], [delta_x_cumul], [delta_y_cumul]], dtype=object)
```

The warning stems from the fact that NumPy does not support jagged arrays natively.

**2. Proper Solution**

Regardless, I'd suggest a more proper solution. Since you want to return a `3xN` matrix, deleting a few superfluous `[` and `]` yields the desired output without throwing any warnings.

```
def get_wheel_status(arr, Dr, Dl, Db):
    
    delta_right = arr[0,:]
    delta_left  = arr[1,:]
    delta_back  = arr[2,:]
    
    delta_theta = (delta_left - delta_right) / (Dr + Dl)
    delta_theta_cumul = np.cumsum(delta_theta, axis=0)
    
    delta_x = 2*np.sin(delta_theta/2) * np.array((delta_back / delta_theta) + Db)
    delta_y = 2*np.sin(delta_theta/2) * np.array((delta_right / delta_theta) + Dr)

    delta_x_cumul = np.cumsum(delta_x, axis=0)
    delta_y_cumul = np.cumsum(delta_y, axis=0)
  
    return np.array([delta_theta_cumul, delta_x_cumul, delta_y_cumul])
```

This yields

```
out = get_wheel_status(arr, 1, 1, 1)
out
>array([[ 1.        ,  2.        ,  4.        ,  5.        ],
        [ 2.87655323,  7.67080862, 17.76846044, 46.53399275],
        [ 4.79425539,  9.58851077, 14.63733668, 22.3081453 ]])

out.shape
>(3, 4)
```